# vSphere folder permissions

Tags: permissions, vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

How do i set permissions on a folder to see al VM's in that folder but do NOT however see an sub-folders that contain VM's?

```
Top-Folder
  - VM-1
  - VM-2
  - SUB-Folder
    -- VM-3
    -- VM-4
```

So in this case to see Top-Folder with VM-1 & VM-2 but not SUB-Folder and it's children?

I have tried removing propagation on the Top-Folder however when this happens i can't see VM-1 & VM-2 either?  I assume because it's children of the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the "No access" role on "SUB-Folder"? That should override the permissions propagated from "Top-Folder" with, well, no access at all.

*edit:*

> "Use the No Access role to mask specific areas of the hierarchy if you do not want for certain users or groups to have access.

[Best Practices for Roles and Permissions](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-FAA074CC-E8C9-4F13-ABCF-6CF7F15F04EE.html)

Comment: This seems to work nicely.  Is this the VMway however, officially?

Comment: @StackUser_py I'd say this is the official way: "Use the No Access role to mask specific areas of the hierarchy if you do not want for certain users or groups to have access." http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-FAA074CC-E8C9-4F13-ABCF-6CF7F15F04EE.html